# Why is this method not only not compiling, but throwing all sorts of nonsensical errors?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compact-framework, windows-ce, .net-1.1

This method, part of a Windows CE / CF / .NET1.1 project:

```
public void createSettingsTable()
{
    public string filename = "\\my documents\\CCRDB.SDF";
    string conStr = "Data Source = " + filename;
    try
    {
        using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(conStr)
        {
            con.Open();
            using (SqlCeCommand com =  new SqlCeCommand("create table ccr_settings (setting_id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,  setting_name varchar(40) not null, setting_value(63) varchar not null)", con))
            {
                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        CCR.ExceptionHandler(ex, "createSettingsTable");
    }
}
```

...is seemingly viewed as something entirely foreign by the compiler. Here are the list of err msgs it causes when I paste it in:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take `public` out of the 3rd line and add a paren to the end of your `using`:

```
public void createSettingsTable()
{
    string filename = "\\my documents\\CCRDB.SDF"; // <- Here
    string conStr = "Data Source = " + filename;
    try
    {
        using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(conStr)) // <- Here
        {
            con.Open();
            using (SqlCeCommand com =  new SqlCeCommand("create table ccr_settings (setting_id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,  setting_name varchar(40) not null, setting_value(63) varchar not null)", con))
            {
                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            //con.Close(); // this is not needed
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        CCR.ExceptionHandler(ex, "createSettingsTable");
    }
}
```

And you don't need that `con.Close` call.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a closing paren at the end of your `using` statement.  Should be this:

```
using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(conStr)) {
  //...
}
```

Comment: Oh, the *first* using; it must be 17 minutes from end-of-day.

Comment: You can remove `con.Close();` as well, the using statement will take care of this.

Comment: @Andy G: Oh, yeah, good catch. I'm combining legacy code with binged code, and didn't notice that.